# Concurrent database MVCC timestamp generation method

Tags: parallel-processing, atomic, database-concurrency, mvcc, nosql

I need to generate database timestamps for MVCC Snapshot isolation.  The typical method utilized:

"Transactional actions are implemented in SI-TM as follows.
TM BEGIN: A logical snapshot for the transaction is generated
by obtaining a unique timestamp using an atomic increment
to the global timestamp counter."

The problem with using this approach in a system with hundreds of cores is that it doesn't scale.  There is a hardware limit of 10M atomic increments per second on a contested memory location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple ideas, and a paper reference:

1) Instead of incrementing the counter by 1, increment it by N, giving clients effectively a range of transaction identifiers [c, c+N). For instance, if N=5, and the initial value of the counter is 1, then clients A, B, and C would get the following:

```
A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
C: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

While this reduces the pressure on the atomic counter, as we can see from this example some clients (like client C) will get a relatively high range of ids while others get lower ranges (client A), and this will lead to higher abort rates in the system.

2) Use ranges of *interleaved* transaction identifiers. This is like 1, but we've added a step variable, S. Here's a simple example: If N=5 and S=3, and the initial value of the counter is 1, then clients A B and C would get the following:

```
A: [1, 4, 7, 10, 13]
B: [2, 5, 8, 11, 14]
C: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

This seems to have solved the problem of 1, but consider client D:

```
D: [16, 19, 22, 25, 28]
```

Now we're back to the same problem that solution #1 had. Tricks must be played with this technique to "get it right".

3) An interesting, but more complex, decentralized way of assigning transaction IDs is described here:

Tu, Stephen, Wenting Zheng, Eddie Kohler, Barbara Liskov, and Samuel Madden. "Speedy transactions in multicore in-memory databases." In Proceedings of the Twenty-Fourth ACM Symposium on Operating Systems Principles, pp. 18-32. ACM, 2013.